# intersect function

Tags: c++

i am checking intersection of two objects.. and i have a class MBR with data meembers low[2] and high[2]..  but i am not getiing intersect..c an you explain this function..

```
intersects(const MBR* h) const
{
 for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) 
 {
  if (low_[i] > h->high_[i] || high_[i] < h->low_[i]) 
   return FALSE;
 }
 return TRUE;
```

Comment: What do you mean by "intersect"? I.e. what are you expecting to happen? (This is why nondescriptive names like "MBR" are bad)

Comment: By "but i am not getiing intersect", I think he is asking what the function "intersects" does. It could just be a function with a coincidental name.

Comment: @irrelephant: Hmm.. I parse that as "I am not getting the calculation I expect, which should be intersection". But I suppose it could be "I don't understand intersect" as well... I suppose this is the problem with not taking the time to not use slang in questions -- it leads to ambiguities when used in writing like this.

Comment: This looks like a function that determines if two rectangles are intersecting... or am I way off?

Comment: I guess MBR stands for Minimum Bounding Rectangle: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_bounding_rectangle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`intersects` compares a MBR to another MBR and returns FALSE if any of the values in the first MBR's `low[]` are greater than the values (in the respective indices) in the second MBR's `high[]` or if any of the values in the first MBR's `high[]` are less than the values (in the respective indices) in the second MBR's `low[]`. Otherwise it returns TRUE.

Comment: +1 -- because this is the correct answer assuming the correct translation of "I don't get intersect" is "I don't understand what the function `intersect` calculates". If the OP replies indicating that this is his intended meaning I will also delete my answer.

Comment: but is this function find intersection? and MBR is actually minimum bounding box

Comment: @piyapiya: that sounds more like you mean "inclusion" rather than "intersection". I.e. you're saying the two points define a quadrilateral, and want to know if one such quadrilateral can fit inside another.

Comment: no no.. see if i draw a MBR and in this i get let say two points.. now i have to apply  9 intersection model on it .. so i am trying to find interior intersect to interior or not.. but i am not getting this .fucntion

Answer (score 1):

Not quite sure what you mean by intersect. If you're talking about intersection of sets, you should probably use `std::set_intersection` rather than trying to implement this kind of thing yourself. Remember that `std::set_intersection` requires that the input is already sorted.

Comment: but in my case user is giving two points p1 and p2 in form of x and y.. now i wan tot find intersect.. if you know about 9 intersection model and MBR minimum bounding box than you will understand it that what i want to do.. but i am not getting this function... how its finding intersection with my class MBR(two data members low[2] and high [2])..

Comment: and one  thing more i am not understanding use of const inside the function, at start and end of the function prototype. plz refer me some link related to only const usage..

Comment: @piyapiya: I am aware of no mathematical concept that speaks of two points being able to "intersect". Two lines or rays, or line segments, maybe, but not points.

Answer (score 1):

If the upper border of one box is smaller than the lower border of another box, than the two boxes don't intersect. Equally, if the lower border of one box is larger than the upper border of the other box. Otherwise the two boxes intersect.

This check is done for both X- and Y-coordinates.